# Rails render_to_string rendering output to body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, react-on-rails

I'm new to Rails and have been trying to get [react_on_rails](https://github.com/shakacode/react_on_rails) to work.
According to the docs, I should be hydrating the redux_store in the controller like this:

```
redux_store 'myStore', props: render_to_string(template: 'action.json.jbuilder')
```

But this causes the controller to output the generated json even for html requests. My controller looks like this:

```
HomeController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :json

  def index
    redux_store 'appStore', props: render_to_string(action: action_name, format: :json)
    # ...
  end
end
```

To my understanding this should add the json string from render_to_string to the redux stores and then render the html body. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this in your action..

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redux_store 'appStore', props: render_to_string(action: action_name, format: :html) }
    format.json { redux_store 'appStore', props: render_to_string(action: action_name, format: :json) }
  end
end
```